# Can't access data from Google Sheet, using Google Sheets API, and C# WPF - Without logging in

Tags: c#, json, google-sheets

Below is the code I use to obtain the data from my spreadsheet. This works if I am logged into google+, but that isn't the intention, as I want users to access the data through this application.

When I build and provide the files to a user on another PC, it doesn't even start the application, on my own, it can at least start

```
        String myUrl =
            "http://nofile.io/g/[REDACTED]/client_secret.json";

        WebClient client = new WebClient(); {
            client.DownloadFile(myUrl, "\\client_secret.json");
        }

        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("\\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        });

        // Define request parameters.
        String spreadsheetId = "1uLxm0jvmL1_FJNYUJp6YqIezzqrZdjPf2xQGOWYd6ao";
        String range = "TestSheet!A1:F";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

        File.Delete("\\client_secret.json");
```

Comment: not every account can write to the root of a drive.. "client.DownloadFile(myUrl, "\\client_secret.json");" ...

Comment: The webclient downloads and saves the .json file - And in the end, deletes it